# Low/Mid/High 230V Fan Control with RaspberryPI

Tags: power

I have fan 230 VAC 300 W, Relay SRD-05VDC-SL-C, and RaspberryPi,

what other equipment i would need to be able to control Fan 230VAC with RaspberryPi?

I want to go 0/1 with relay, and in mode:1, be able to control Low/Mid/High Fan Speed.

Thanks

Comment: Ah, let me see.  Perhaps you can use a Rpi GPIO pin in PWM mode to control relay. You might also like to add the following bells and whistles: (1) A temperature sensor such as DHT22 as a feedback to Rpi, (2) A real time clock such as DT3231 for real time scheduling and time record keeping, (3)  An ACS712 or similar based current sensor to monitor current and power etc. (4)  Display and manual control panel, based on smart phone or LCD/LED touch display.